# How to fix input text after paste using JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to paste mnemonic phrase 24 words in one of 24 empty text fields and then distribute them in one word per field. It's work, but field, that used, contain "his" word and whole mnemonic phrase. How to fix it?
`

```
const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePasteAnywhere = event => {

      mnemonics = event.clipboardData.getData('text').split(' ');
      
      if(mnemonics.length >= 24){
        let j = 0;
        mnemonics.map(function(i){

          if(j < 24){
            inputs[j].value = i;
          }
          

          j++;
         
        })
      }

    };

    window.addEventListener('paste', handlePasteAnywhere);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('paste', handlePasteAnywhere);
    };
  }, []);
```

`

```
mnemonics.map((i) => (
                  <Form.Control
                    className="mnemonic"
                    name="mnemonic"
                    type="text"
                    onPaste={handlePaste}
                    />
                  
                ))
```

`
sample mnemonic
inhale piece click logic uncle over surge oyster accident coral logic harsh crater avoid spread exchange brown rabbit feed scale wrestle pepper affair memory

first field used for paste contain: inhaleinhale piece click logic uncle over surge oyster accident coral logic harsh crater avoid spread exchange brown rabbit feed scale wrestle pepper affair memory

I paste mnemonic phrase to field inputs[0]
After script field contain : "inhaleinhale piece click logic uncle over surge oyster accident coral logic harsh crater avoid spread exchange brown rabbit feed scale wrestle pepper affair memory"

just "inhale" expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
const handlePaste = event => {
const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
const mnemonics = event.clipboardData.getData('text').split(' ');
  
if(mnemonics.length >= 24){
  let j = 0;
  mnemonics.map(function(i){
    if(j < 24){
      inputs[j].value = i+" ";
    }
    j++;
  })
}
// fix used field
setTimeout(function() {event.target.value = event.target.value.split(' ')[0]+' ';}, 0);
return;
```

};